# LanguageTool Java app running as a systemd service. `--languagemodel` argument is ignored

Tags: linux, nginx, systemd, init.d, languagetool

I have downloaded the [LanguageTool server](http://wiki.languagetool.org/http-server). I have created a systemd process for the app to ensure that it can be easily managed and begins on startup:

## Systemd

```
[Unit]
Description=LanguageTool Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/languagetool
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -cp /usr/local/LangAnalysisApp/LangTool/LanguageTool-4.9/languagetool-server.jar org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer --port 8081 --languagemodel /mnt/languagetool-volume/languagetool-ngrams --allow-origin '*'
StandardOutput=syslog+console+/var/log/languagetool.log
StandardError=syslog+console+/var/log/languagetool.log
User=www-data
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The port is exposed via nginx as follows:

## NGINX

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    root /var/www/my.domain.com/public_html;

    index index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/my.domain.com-error.log error;

    location /v2/check {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/v2/check;
    }

}
```

The `--languagemodel` option is ignored. If I type it improperly, then I see errors. The argument in the process file does not throw any errors, so it must be recognised by the system. The test n-grams displayed [here](http://wiki.languagetool.org/finding-errors-using-n-gram-data) do not return any results, though, so I know it's not loading properly.

I would like to know how to make the `--languagemodel` option work with systemd.

Comment: For nginx which file do we need to modify?

Comment: @Porcupine it would go in a new file '/etc/nginx/sites-available/my.domain.com' an then you can create a symlink with 'ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/my.domain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/'. Finally, restart nginx with 'sudo systemctl restart nginx'.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said but I get systemctl error 216 (Failed to determine or change group credentials). So I added Group=www-data. I checked that www-data exists as Group and User in Ubuntu 20.04. Also, nginx is configured as this user. But even after adding Group=www-data, I get the same error. Also, may I ask what is the purpose of  exposing the port via nginx? Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: Hi sorry for the slow reply. I don't know about that error, but if systemd is trying to change the group credentials then maybe that means the file is not owned by www-data?

RE: exposing the port... I am creating separate web applications to make the API calls to the LanguageTool server so, for my use case, the easiest way is to expose the port and make requests over HTTP. If you are integrating LanguageTool into your application itself then you probably don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the capitalisation was important. The `--languageModel` option is only recognised by systemd when written in camel case.

Second, the error was not any fault of my own, but resulted from a bug within the current version of LanguageTool. A fix is mentioned [here](https://forum.languagetool.org/t/sth-wrong-when-i-am-useing-ngram-on-the-server/5507). Using a snapshot of version `5.0` fixes the error. External n-grams are now used to generate results. The version `4.9.1` is due to be released within the next few days and contains a fix for the bug.